# How to access scikit-learn's cross validation X and Y scores?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I'm using scikit-learn's linear regression in combination with (k-fold) cross validation. Now, to calculate a t-test I need access to my array of errors (y_test - y_pred).

```
# Load dataset
smartphone = pd.read_csv('all-users_w4_filtered.csv')

# Define Independent variable (X) and Dependent variable (Y)  
x=smartphone[['mood_mean', 'valence_mean', 'app.social_mean', 'app.other_mean']].values
y=smartphone['target'].values
z=smartphone['benchmark'].values

# Reshape data
x = x.reshape(-1, 4)
y = y.reshape(-1, 1)

# First shuffle the data, then perform k-fold cross-validation
kf = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
scores = cross_val_score(regr, x, y, cv=kf)
print ('5-fold shuffled cross validation scores: ', scores)
print ('Mean of cross-validation:', scores.mean())

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(x):
   #print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
   X_train, X_test = x[train_index], x[test_index]
   y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

Output of scores:

> 5-fold shuffled cross validation scores:  [ 0.21801002  0.3282497
>   0.27146692  0.36056872  0.29064657] Mean of cross-validation: 0.293788384892

How do I access the arrays of y_pred which is used to calculate the MSE's in cross_val_score?

I tried replicating using regr.fit / regr.predict on the indexed data in the loop, but this yielded different results.

Comment: First, if `regr` variable in your code is a regressor, it will not calculate MSE as you are thinking. It will calculate R-squared value, unless otherwise specified. Second, you cannot get what you want in `cross_val_score`. You need to implement the for loop yourself.

Comment: Right, thanks! That's why I had such a problem replicating the scores.